# Java HTTP DELETE with Request Body

Tags: java, http

I have an external API which uses DELETE with the body(JSON). I make use of Postman REST Client and get the delete done with request body and it works fine. I am trying to automate this functionality using a method.

I tried HttpURLConnection for similar GET, POST and PUT. But I am not sure how to use the DELETE with a request body.

I have checked in StackOverflow and see this cannot be done, but they are very old answers.

Can someone please help? I'm using spring framework.

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299628/is-an-entity-body-allowed-for-an-http-delete-request. It seems that with DELETE, the request body should be ignored.

Comment: I have read that article, however, the external API which I use has to have the body

Comment: Which third-party API is this? Is it a third-party API used by a third-party product, or a third-party API used by a product you are developing? In the former case, you're pretty much stuck with it, but in the latter case, your organization could choose to use a library with a more common (better supported) syntax.

Comment: It's an in-house application service of my org, accessible only through the same network. I'm trying to hit that production API with my API.

Comment: Typically only POST, PUT and PATCH use request bodies, so at least that is not a REST API - seems to be a bad design at all.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used org.apache.http to get this done.

```
@NotThreadSafe
class HttpDeleteWithBody extends HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase {
    public static final String METHOD_NAME = "DELETE";

    public String getMethod() {
        return METHOD_NAME;
    }

    public HttpDeleteWithBody(final String uri) {
        super();
        setURI(URI.create(uri));
    }

    public HttpDeleteWithBody(final URI uri) {
        super();
        setURI(uri);
    }

    public HttpDeleteWithBody() {
        super();
    }
}



public String[] sendDelete(String URL, String PARAMS, String header) throws IOException {
    String[] restResponse = new String[2];
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.createDefault();

        HttpDeleteWithBody httpDelete = new HttpDeleteWithBody(URL);
        StringEntity input = new StringEntity(PARAMS, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        httpDelete.addHeader("header", header);
        httpDelete.setEntity(input);  

        Header requestHeaders[] = httpDelete.getAllHeaders();
        CloseableHttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpDelete);
        restResponse[0] = Integer.toString((response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()));
        restResponse[1] = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());    
        return restResponse;
    }
}
```

Comment: Got the answer from
https://daweini.wordpress.com/2013/12/20/apache-httpclient-send-entity-body-in-a-http-delete-request/

Answer (score 5):

If you are using Spring, you can use `RestTemplate` to generate the client request. In this case you could use [RestTemplate.exchange](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#exchange-java.net.URI-org.springframework.http.HttpMethod-org.springframework.http.HttpEntity-java.lang.Class-) and provide the url, http method and request body. Something like (not tested, but you get the idea):

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
HttpEntity<Foo> request = new HttpEntity<>(new Foo("bar"));
restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.DELETE, request, null);
```

Comment: This will drop the body and always return 400

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me:-

- You set content type by httpCon.setRequestProperty
- You set the request Method by httpCon.setRequestMethod
- Write the json body into OutputStreamWriter, in my sample, i converted Java object to json using Jackson ObjectMapper

  ```
  URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/greeting");
  HttpURLConnection httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  httpCon.setDoOutput(true);
  httpCon.setRequestProperty(
                  "Content-Type", "application/json");
  httpCon.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
  OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(
                  httpCon.getOutputStream());
  ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
  out.write(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(new Greeting("foo")));
  out.close();
  httpCon.connect();
  ```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't easy just to override the `getMethod()` method of the `HttpPost` class?

```
private String curl(                    // Return JSON String
        String method,                  // HTTP method, for this example the method parameter should be "DELETE", but it could be PUT, POST, or GET.
        String url,                     // Target URL  
        String path,                    // API Path
        Map<String, Object> queryParams,// Query map forms URI
        Map<String, Object> postParams) // Post Map serialized to JSON and is put in the header
        throws Error,               // when API returns an error
        ConnectionClosedException       // when we cannot contact the API
{
   HttpClient client = HttpClients.custom()
            .setDefaultRequestConfig(
                    RequestConfig.custom()
                            .setCookieSpec(CookieSpecs.STANDARD)
                            .build()
            ).build();


    HttpPost req = new HttpPost(){
        @Override
        public String getMethod() {
            // lets override the getMethod since it is the only
            // thing that differs between each of the subclasses
            // of HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase. Let's just return
            // our method parameter in the curl method signature.
            return method;
        }
    };

    // set headers
    req.setHeader("user-agent", "Apache");
    req.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    req.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");

    try {
        // prepare base url
        URIBuilder uriBuilder = new URIBuilder(url + path);

        if (method.equals("GET")){
            queryParams.forEach((k, v)-> uriBuilder.addParameter(k, v.toString()));
        }else{
            String postPramsJson = new Gson().toJson(postParams);
            req.setEntity(new StringEntity(postPramsJson));
        }

        // set the uri
        req.setURI(uriBuilder.build().normalize());

        // execute the query
        final HttpResponse response = client.execute(req);

        //
        if (response.getEntity() != null) {
            if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                 return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }
            logger.error("ERROR: Response code " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() +
                     ", respnse: " + EntityUtils.toString(responseEntry));
        }
        throw new Error("HTTP Error");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Connection error", e);
        throw new ConnectionClosedException("Cannot connect to " + url);
    }
}
```

The point is rather than having to add another class to your package... Why not just override `getMethod()` in an already sub-classed object of `HttpEntityEnclosingRequestBase`?